# PS/2 keyboard stopped working

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, hardware-failure

I have a Rosewill PS/2 mechanical keyboard on my main PC, used it for a little over a year now. Every so often, for seemingly no reason Windows would stop recognizing the keyboard. This while computer is still on and running normally.

After the first time this happened, I got fairly used to the process of fixing it. Turns out a registry key (I8042prt) would have been somehow modified, and I would have to reset it's value.

Yesterday, it happened again. After reading an article, I was about to look up something up, when I realized the keyboard isn't working.

This time however, I've not been able to fix it as usual. I've checked the registry, but no dice. If I unplug the keyboard and plug it back in, the indicator lights flash to let me know it has power, but then no response.

The registry key I used to edit to fix this problem is the following:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/i8042prt/Start
```

Comment: When this happens, does the keyboard start working with a simple reboot? Have you been able to try another PS/2 and/or USB keyboard, to rule out a hardware problem with the keyboard or the PS/2 port itself?

Comment: No, it used to require me changing the registry and then rebooting. This time that hasn't worked. I do not have another PS/2 keyboard, unfortunately.

Comment: Just for your information: A PS/2 interface is not like a USB interface. If you unplug it, and plug it back in, it will not work until you reboot the computer. This is because a PS/2 device has to be properly initialized by the BIOS. This is why the leds flash indicating its not properly initialized but it has power.

Comment: What registry key are you changing exactly?  You have tried rebooted the computer correct?

Comment: I added the registry key to the problem. I did reboot the computer. I also tried accessing the BIOS (UEFI). But then the computer would stall on a black screen. I was able to reach it using the Windows Boot into UEFI.